# Theories relevant to institutional quality and economic development

Tags: reference-request, theory, development, development-economics

I want to write a term paper on institutional quality and economic development. What will be its possible theoretical framework?

Comment: The "inventor" of the terminology is Nobel Prize winner Douglass C. North who sadly passed away 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following researchers have written a number of papers and books on this topic:

- [Doran Acemoglu](http://economics.mit.edu/faculty/acemoglu/publication)
- [James Robinson](http://scholar.harvard.edu/jrobinson/category/categories/published-paper)

You may want to read their papers for a good start.

Comment: That Acemoglu and Robinson overestimated the role of institutions in the past is almost consensus by now. There seems to be no clear causal relationship. A lot of recent papers show that it is not primarily the institutions that determine whether countries are rich or poor (see e.g. http://qje.oxfordjournals.org/content/129/1/151.abstract)